# Why CFloat and CDouble?? func addNewValue(newVal: CFloat, atTime time: CDouble) -> CFloat {}

Tags: swift

I converted

```
-(float) addNewValue:(float) newVal atTime:(double) time {
```

to

```
func addNewValue(newVal: CFloat, atTime time: CDouble) -> CFloat {}
```

There are no errors but I don't know why it works. Why do `Float` and `Double` become `CFloat` and `CDouble`?

There are also no errors with:

```
func addNewValue(newVal: Float, atTime time: Double) -> Float {}
```

So which am I supposed to use?

Full code

```
let maxPeriod:Double = 1.5
let minPeriod:Double = 0.1
let invalidEntry = -100
let maxPeriodsToStore = 20
let averageSize:Int = 20


class Detector {

    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    var camera : AVCaptureDevice?

    var upVals = [averageSize]
    var downVals = [averageSize]
    var upValIndex: Int?
    var downValIndex: Int?

    var lastVal: Float?
    var periodStart: Float?
    var periods = [maxPeriodsToStore] 
    var periodTimes = [maxPeriodsToStore]

    var periodIndex: Int?
    var started: Bool?
    var freq: Float?
    var average: Float?

    var wasDown: Bool?


    func reset() {


        for var i:Int = 0; i < maxPeriodsToStore; i++ {
            periods[i] = invalidEntry
        }
        for var i:Int = 0; i < averageSize; i++ {
            upVals[i] = invalidEntry
            downVals[i] = invalidEntry
        }
        freq = 0.5
        periodIndex = 0
        downValIndex = 0
        upValIndex = 0
    }

    // SO Question is regarding this function

    func addNewValue(newVal: Float, atTime time: Double) -> Float {
    // we keep track of the number of values above and below zero
    if newVal > 0 {
    upVals[upValIndex!] = newVal
    upValIndex!++
    if upValIndex >= averageSize {
    upValIndex = 0
    }
    }
    if newVal < 0 {
    downVals[downValIndex!] -= newVal
    downValIndex!++
    if downValIndex! >= averageSize as! Int {
    downValIndex = 0
    }
    }
    // work out the average value above zero
    var count: Float
    var total: Float
    for var i=0; i < averageSize; i++ {
    if upVals[i] != invalidEntry {
    count++
    total += upVals[i]
    }
    }
    var averageUp = total/count
    // and the average value below zero
    count=0;
    total=0;
    for var i=0; i < averageSize; i++ {
    if downVals[i] != invalidEntry {
    count++
    total+=downVals[i]
    }
    }
    var averageDown = total/count

    // is the new value a down value?
    if newVal < (-0.5*averageDown) {
    wasDown = true
    }

    // is the new value an up value and were we previously in the down state?
    if (newVal >= (0.5*averageUp) && (wasDown) != nil) {
    wasDown = false

    // work out the difference between now and the last time this happenned
    if (time - periodStart) < maxPeriod && (time - periodStart) > minPeriod {
    periods[periodIndex]=time-periodStart
    periodTimes[periodIndex]=time
    periodIndex++
    if periodIndex >= maxPeriodsToStore {
                periodIndex = 0
    }
    }
    // track when the transition happened
    periodStart = time
    }
    // return up or down
    if newVal < (-0.5*averageDown) {
    return -1
    } else if newVal > (0.5*averageUp) {
    return 1
    }
    return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So which am I supposed to use?

Float and Double. The terms CFloat and CDouble are merely typealiases (synonyms) for these, so there is no point using them; they are there merely for compatibility.

Comment: Thanks guys. Weird that the docs don't even say it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Because Swift is an entirely different language than C.

Objective-C (which is an extension of the C language) can use C-types like `float` and `double`, but Swift has to define their own interpretations of these.

More information can be found [in the Primitive Types section of this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html).

Comment: Ok yeah but why do they become CFloat/CDouble and not just stay as Float/Double? I checked that doc. It says use Int wherever possible in Swift but doesn't give a reason why CFloat would become Float. I've been using the regular Swift Float everywhere else in my conversion so why not here?

Comment: Probably because the Float and Double you're using everywhere else are purely Swift native types, while the `float` and `double` you *converted* became equivalents to the C types.  And at a lower level, like the compiler, there can be differences in the size and characteristics of different types.

Comment: The thing I'm worried about is when I change it to `func addNewValue(newVal: Float, atTime time: Double) -> Float {}` there are no errors as well so I'm not sure what to use. I posted the full code so you could see. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see you using any c functions, at least on my first look through of your full code.  I think you are fine using "`Double`" and "`Float`" the way you are.